# How to execute async methods in Order?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I have a custom asynchronous method and I know threads are executed randomly, but I want to execute them in order.

I want to solve the problem in the `main()` method.

I've tried `Thread.sleep()` but it's not useful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{      
      Monster monster = new Monster();

      System.out.println(1);
      monster.exe();
      System.out.println(2);
      monster.exe();
      System.out.println(3);
      monster.exe();
      System.out.println(4);
}
```

Class `Monster`

```
class Monster {

    public void exe() {

        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Monster...: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: ??? If you want them executed sequentially, then don't code them as separate threads.  Your question is unclear, and may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Re, "threads are executed randomly." FYI the word is "concurrently." When you cannot prove that events within a program happen in a certain order, then we say that the events happen concurrently. And, FYI, making events happen concurrently is the _only_ thing that threads are good for. What you're asking here is like saying, "I need to use a hammer, but I need to not use it for hitting anything."

Answer (score 1):

That's doable, but frankly pointless because such a "parallel" execution even less performant than *sequential* processing of these tasks.

If you are doing that just as an *exercise*, that's OK. Otherwise, either don't try to control the execution of these tasks or do it in a single-threaded environment.

For that, you might use method [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Monster monster = new Monster();
    System.out.println(1);
    Thread thread1 = monster.exe();
    thread1.join();
    System.out.println(2);
    Thread thread2 = monster.exe();
    thread2.join();
    System.out.println(3);
    Thread thread3 = monster.exe();
    thread3.join();
    System.out.println(4);
}
```

Each call of `join()` will block the *main thread* until *another thread* (on which this method was invoked) isn't finished its job.

***Note***: method `join()` throws `InterruptedException` which is a *checked exception* and must be either handled with a `try/catch` or should be signified in the method declaration. I've deliberately chosen the second option in order to make the code simpler and keep focus on what it is intended to do. But you should know that it's not a good practice to add the `throws` clause to the declaration of the `main()` method.

A small change was done to the `Monster` class (*method* `exe()` *returns a thread that has been created in order to be able to join on it*).

```
public class Monster {
    
    public Thread exe() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Monster...: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
        thread.start();
        return thread;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1
Monster...: Thread-0
2
Monster...: Thread-1
3
Monster...: Thread-2
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to extract the codes that you want to execute asynchronously into a separate `Runnable` :

```java
 Runnable newMonstorTask() {
     return ()->System.out.println("Monster...: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

And then use `CompletableFuture` to configure them to execute in order and asynchronously :

```java
 CompletableFuture.runAsync(newMonstorTask())
        .thenRunAsync(newMonstorTask())
        .thenRunAsync(newMonstorTask())
        .thenRunAsync(newMonstorTask());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CompletableFuture` and then methods like `thenApply()`.

Please look here: https://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/